# Support For Elastic Beanstalk on LocalStack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, localstack

I am rather new to LocalStack and I am finding it to be extremely useful.  The [LocalStack GitHub page](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) does not list Elastic Beanstalk as a supported service.  Is there any information on whether this will be rolled out anytime soon?

Answer (score 3):

Elasticbeanstalk automatically creates the infrastructure necessary to deploy and run your application in the cloud. For example. it creates EC2 instances, load balancer etc for you.

if you look at localstack, it supports the standalone services such IAM, S3, Dynamodb etc. Therefore I don't think the localstack will ever support elasticbeanstalk as a service.

If you want to simulate running the elasticbeanstalk application locally,  you can try running the following the eb cli command. It will run the application in docker.

```
eb local run
```